# How do I implement multiple interfaces with public properties but private set methods?

Tags: c#, interface, access-modifiers

I have two interfaces:

```cs
public interface IFooFile
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IFooProduct
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

I'm wanting to implement both with private sets:

```cs
public class AFooThing : IFooFile, IFooProduct
{
    public string IFooFile.Name { get; private set; }
    public string IFooProduct.Name { get; private set; }
}
```

But the access modifiers are creating the error:

> The accessor of the "AFooThing.IFooFile.Name.set" must be more restrictive than the property or indexer "AFooThing.IFooFile.Name"

If I implement the class like this, I get no access modifier errors but I don't have the second interface:

```cs
public class AFooThing : IFooFile
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

**I can't figure out how to have both interfaces implemented with the added "private set" without causing problems. What is the proper way to handle this?**

Comment: Do you need 2 Name properties?  If so, _why_?  Does that not strike you as odd?

Comment: If you just need to satisfy both interfaces, just implement them both with the _one_ `Name` property.  See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BeEtFb)

Comment: @maccettura That only works if the same name applies to both properties. A product could allow slashes in the name and wouldn't need an extension. It works for `ICollection.Count` and `ICollection<T>.Count` because they're conceptually the same.

Comment: @maccettura They are two different formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use access modifiers for an explicit interface, it is `public`. Also you could not add `set` property as it does not exist in the `interface`. What you can do is achieve your goal by using backing fields, e.g.

```
public class AFooThing : IFooFile, IFooProduct
{
    private string _fooFileName;
    private string _fooProductName;

    string IFooFile.Name => _fooFileName;
    string IFooProduct.Name => _fooProductName;

    public AFooThing()
    {
        _fooFileName = "FooFileName";
        _fooProductName = "FooProductName";
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work and it makes sense why it would need to be done this way. It's just more code than I was hoping for because there's a decent amount of them. Thanks for your help.